# how to make same size of width of <td> in two table?

Tags: css

How to make the width of yellow background fit to the width of gray background at http://plekz.com/home.php ?

my current code :

```
    <table style="width:920px;"> 
         //yellow background tr for header of table
    </table>

<div style="overflow:auto; height:500px; border-bottom:1px blue solid; width:940px;">
    <table style="width:920px;">
        //gray background tr for body of table
    </table>
</div>
```

i don't want to wrap table header in an overflow div, I just want to wrap table body in an overflow div. How to do that in a single table? if can't do in single table, then i do in two different tables, the width of td will be different if do in two table, I have tried to put in width:920px to both table, its doesn't help.

Updated answer :
Finally I manage to fix the problem by myself. I think the problem happen because width of table is not enough to hold all `<td>`, so it auto reduce width of any 1 or 2 `<td>` in table 1 and table 2. We can't decide which `<td>` to be reduced its width, html/css random pick any `<td>` to be reduced its width. So the solution to the problem is to increase the width for the 2 tables from 920px to 1000px.

Comment: Why not just apply the background to the table itself?

Comment: @WTP, If put background on table itself, there will be no border lines anymore... I want border lines

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just add an `class` to each `<table>` and set a width in css? Something like this:

HTML:

```
<div style="width:920px;">
    <table class='myclass'> 
         //table title with yellow background
    </table>
</div>
<div style="overflow:auto; height:500px; border-bottom:1px blue solid; width:940px;">
    <table class='myclass'>
        //table records with gray background
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.myclass {
    width: 920px;
}
```

Comment: you don't understand my question.

Comment: you don't feel like clarifying what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: i don't want to wrap table header in an overflow div, I just want to wrap table body in an overflow div. How to do that in a single table? if can't do in single table, then i do in two different tables, the width of td will be different if do in two table, I have tried to put in width:920px to both table, its doesn't help, you can use firebug to check it on http://plekz.com/home.php ?

Comment: your example here: http://plekz.com/home.php seems to be working in FF - what is the problem you're having with that? Also, check out this article, it seems to be related... http://www.ssi-developer.net/css/non-scrolling-table-hdr.shtml

Comment: from my example, don't you see the column "Visitor" header is wider than its records/values? The website u showed me also has this problem, but they just ignore the problem, they didn't discuss about the problem there. I am looking a solution to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

use one table, for header use thead and for body tbody

Comment: cannot do that because html not allow to have div in a table. I want to wrap body of table inside <div style="overflow:auto;> but header of table outside the div

Comment: did you try to add height and overflow to tbody?

Comment: table doesn't have the property for overflow. Overflow can use for <div> only, cannot use for <table>

Comment: when displaying block it does

Comment: tasted, overflow + display block is working on firefox, fail on ie and chrome. Although it is working on firefox but the width is still different, the output is worse than applying overflow on div previously.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you're asking but have you tried using  for the yellow header cells and grey for rest of the  cells. That way you'll only require on table and ensure they're always the same width?

```
<table> 
        <tr>
            <th></th> // Yellow th cells
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td> // Gret td cells
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td> // Gret td cells
        </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I want to wrap body of table inside a `<div>` but header of table outside the `<div>`. HTML doesn't allow put in a `<div>` in `<table>` , that's why I must use two tables...

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to use CSS to hard code the width of your table cells...

Put the following in your stylesheet:

```
table td { width: 50px /* Change to whatever you want */ }
```

Comment: all td have different sizes, and i already assigned width to all td of table body to be same size as the td width of table header, but the problem is still there. U can use firebug to confirm it.

Comment: I have tried both style="width:80px;" and width="80px", but both also can't fix the problem.